# Do we need to rescale image before predicting with model, trained with ImageDataGen 1./255?

Tags: python, image, keras

I have trained my own simple single class CNN on image datagen with rescale  1./255.
Accuracy on train and test looks fine.
When I'm predicting on some new images using test datagen with rescale - results pretty good.
But when I'm trying to predict by single images - I'm having troubles. If I use manual rescale /255 - results very poor. If I skip this step and pass to model original image - predict seems fine.
What I'm doing wrong?
It is logical to me that if model trained on rescaled data [0..1] (as it should for neural networks), predict also should be on rescaled data. No?

My datagens:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   rotation_range=35,
                                   shear_range = 0.15,
                                   zoom_range = 0.15,
                                   brightness_range=[0.5,1.1],
                                   horizontal_flip = False,
                                   preprocessing_function = apply_mask)

valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(path_train,
                                                 target_size = img_size, 
                                                 batch_size = batch_size,
                                                 class_mode = "binary")

valid_set = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(path_test,
                                            target_size = img_size,
                                            batch_size = batch_size,
                                            class_mode = "binary")
```

Network:

```
initializer = glorot_normal()
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (img_size[0], img_size[1], 3), activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer=initializer, padding='same')) #, padding='same'
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer=initializer))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer=initializer))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.4))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer=identity()))
classifier.add(Dense(1))
classifier.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

Training network:

```
history = classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 1 * int(np.ceil(nb_train_samples / batch_size)),
                         epochs = 150,
                         validation_data = valid_set, 
                         validation_steps = 1 * int(np.ceil(nb_validation_samples / batch_size)),
                         callbacks=[earlyStopping, mcp_save, reduce_lr_loss])
```

Predct by datagen:

```
test_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
test_data_generator = test_generator.flow_from_directory(path_test,
                                            target_size = img_size,
                                            batch_size = batch_size,
                                            shuffle = False,
                                            class_mode = "binary")
test_steps_per_epoch = np.math.ceil(test_data_generator.samples / test_data_generator.batch_size)
predictions = model.predict_generator(test_data_generator, steps=test_steps_per_epoch)
```

Predict using manual image import:

```
valid_images = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png"]

for filename in os.listdir(predict_path):        
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
        continue                
    file = predict_path + "/" + filename
    test_image = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(file, target_size = img_size)
    test_image = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(test_image).astype(np.float32)
    test_image /= 255.
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
    result = model.predict(test_image)
    print(result)
    if result[0][0] == 1:
        prediction = 'True'
    else:
        prediction = 'Not True'
    print(prediction)
    img = Image.open(file)
    display(img)
    print("\n")
    print("\n")
```

More interesting - if I use image normalization before predict - sigmoid predicted results became float [0..1], if I just comment `test_image /= 255.`  - results again binary 0,1.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if the output layer is '1' or not. Sigmoid normally generates a number between 0 and 1. It can be '1' or can be less than 1. You should use a threshold value. And the threshold can be 0.5 or any other value which can be decided by judging the data. Let's say your threshold value is 0.5. If your model output is greater than 0.5, then it's 1 otherwise consider it 0.

In your code, you're comparing with 1. So, your threshold is 1.0. You will barely get output value 1 from your model with sigmoid activation. Set the threshold lower. Try with 0.5 first.

Everything else seems fine. If you're using scaled input for training, then you should scale the input before prediction too.

Comment: Actually no, I'm training model as 2 class model - True and False, using flow_from_directory I have `0` and `1` folders for train and test.

Comment: @Oleksii I think you should study more about it. There is no such logic that you'll get the same output as input. The output of a neuron completely depends on the activation function. And you're using the sigmoid. It always outputs a number ranging between 0 and 1 depending on the input. Not necessarily always the rounded 1. You will get 1 only for extreme cases. For this type of model normally we do use threshold value. let's say your threshold is 0.5. If your output is 0.5, consider it 1 otherwise 0. But you set it to 1. So maximum of your output will be considered as 0.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you have only 1 neuron in output layer. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, yes. But I dont understand why it's an issue to have single output neuron with sigmoid?   I have 2 classes in train and test, output neuron with sigmoid activation can output values from 0 to 1, where closer to 0 - it's first class (flase), closer to 1 - second (true).  I've add threshold 0.5 by replacing `if result[0][0] == 1:` to   `if np.round(result[0][0],0) == 1:`

Comment: @Oleksii That's another question. You can take a look here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-sigmoid-function-and-what-is-its-use-in-machine-learnings-neural-networks-How-about-the-sigmoid-derivative-function

Please accept my answer if it really solves your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**The last activation should be 'ReLU' layer not sigmoid**, now do the same thing.

> Should resolve your problem, actually 'sigmoid' layer gives a fractional output between 0-1. You are comparing results with 1 only. That's a problem. Using 'relu' instead

Comment: No, I'm predicting 2 classes - is it `class 1` or everything else (`class 0`). So, sigmoid is ok.

Comment: Even relu is ok, The problem with your code is your output is probability. **your logic if prob is 1, class is 1** is not sensible. You don't know over what is the boundary probabilty to classify, and you shouldn't know that, it will be machine learned. On other thoughts, directly use this if you want to stick to sigmoid ```prediction=model.predict_classes(test_image)```

Comment: Although ```model.predict_classes``` works, the best practice in this regard is convert this into a two class problem.